# Adding a program to DEP exception list with code or launch process with DEP disabled

Tags: c#, windows, process, dep

I need to add a program to the `DEP` exception list through code.

One way is to add it to the Registry, but I would prefer to do it some other way if possible.

Alternatively, launching the process with DEP disabled would be okay as well, but I haven't figured out how that's possible. Using `CreateRemoteThread` to call `SetProcessDEPPolicy` immediately after the program launches is already too late, since `DEP` is set upon process creation.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please add more details on your use-case, be more specific on what you exactly want, and as well got through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What area do you suggest adding details? My question captures my full intent, as specifically as I needed it to be.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]